# How to access input value in a form CreateView using Django?

Tags: django

Let's say I have a form to create an animal(name, color ...), how to access the input value and display it (after the form has been submitted) in the same form page.

I tried :

```
class AnimalCreate(CreateView):
  model = Animal
  form_class = AnimalForm
  success_url = 'main_site/success.html'
  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    color = ?? # how to get the value of the color input ?
    context = super(AnimalCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['color'] = color
    return context
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    if self.request.method == 'POST':
        color = self.request.POST.get('color')
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a standard Django HTML form, try getting the parameters using `self.request.POST`.

Otherwise, if you're working with Django Rest Framework or sending JSON data instead of a form, try `self.request.data`.